# confusion with Model Attribute in java class

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have a bit confuse with the concept of Model and @ModelAttribute

Lets say I have two files:

UserController.java /User.java

In UserController.java

```
public class UserController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView user() {
      User user = new User();      
      user.setFavoriteFrameworks((new String []{"Spring MVC","Struts 2"}));
      user.setGender("M");
      ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user", "command", user);
      return modelAndView;
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")User user, 
      ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
      model.addAttribute("password", user.getPassword());
      model.addAttribute("address", user.getAddress());
      model.addAttribute("receivePaper", user.isReceivePaper());
      model.addAttribute("favoriteFrameworks", user.getFavoriteFrameworks());
      model.addAttribute("gender", user.getGender());
      model.addAttribute("favoriteNumber", user.getFavoriteNumber());
      model.addAttribute("country", user.getCountry());     
      return "userlist";
   }

   @ModelAttribute("webFrameworkList")
   public List<String> getWebFrameworkList()
   {
      List<String> webFrameworkList = new ArrayList<String>();
      webFrameworkList.add("Spring MVC");
      webFrameworkList.add("Struts 1");
      webFrameworkList.add("Struts 2");
      webFrameworkList.add("Apache Wicket");
      return webFrameworkList;
   }
```

In User.class

```
package com.yiibai.springmvc;
public class User {

   private String username;
   private String password;
   private String address;
   private boolean receivePaper;
   private String [] favoriteFrameworks;   
   private String gender;
   private String favoriteNumber;
   private String country;

   public String getUsername() {
      return username;
   }
   public void setUsername(String username) {
      this.username = username;
   }

   public String getPassword() {
      return password;
   }
   public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
   }
   public String getAddress() {
      return address;
   }
   public void setAddress(String address) {
      this.address = address;
   }
   public boolean isReceivePaper() {
      return receivePaper;
   }
   public void setReceivePaper(boolean receivePaper) {
      this.receivePaper = receivePaper;
   }
   public String[] getFavoriteFrameworks() {
      return favoriteFrameworks;
   }
   public void setFavoriteFrameworks(String[] favoriteFrameworks) {
      this.favoriteFrameworks = favoriteFrameworks;
   }
   public String getGender() {
      return gender;
   }
   public void setGender(String gender) {
      this.gender = gender;
   }
   public String getFavoriteNumber() {
      return favoriteNumber;
   }
   public void setFavoriteNumber(String favoriteNumber) {
      this.favoriteNumber = favoriteNumber;
   }
   public String getCountry() {
      return country;
   }
   public void setCountry(String country) {
      this.country = country;
   }
}
```

As for my understanding, Model basically means Entity class, which is refer to User.class.

Question 1:

So in "/user" , this method will always return User.class as model. But in UserController, there are some @ModelAttribute at the start of method. Does it means the returned model object will backed with this extra property?

Question 2:

I can see that, in /addUser,  @ModelAttribute also added with in method too, what is the purpose here? Does the model here also refer to the user class I have sent to view previously ?

Answer (score 0):

-> by using Model we send data from controller to model
-> @ModelAttribute is used to get data or object from view to controller

Comment: As for my understanding, controller is always the first part being processing before View. So, I wonder how controller could work on model initially when there is no view pass him any model?

Answer (score 0):

In UserController @ModelAttribute will give the user with same property which already present in the User.java class. The @ModelAttribute annotation helps to get the data in a binding format.

When /user is called the user model is sent to the view page where we put some data into that user model property and the data is store in that model than with the click of submit button the same User model comes to the addUser method with data and we can process that. The purpose of that attribute is instead of access the individual data we can get the whole data.

Comment: when you said  "When /user is called the user model is sent to the view page", I dont understand why the function can send an model to view. Isnt that the model is part of the parameter, which it is expected to be passed by view? 

But if passing way of model is only by view, how could the controller have a model initially? @Kaushik Shaw

Comment: In the MVC architecture model is used to send the data between controllers to view. From the view page if you want to get the data you have to access each data individual but with the help of the model, it was easy because in the model we pass the object to the view and in view, we get that empty object then we put the data to the property of that object and when we click submit the same object with the form data we can access once no need to access individual data. we set the object to the model in the controller and spring gives that model object .